# "Apply for a job" pode ser traduzido como "aplicar para um emprego"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, tradução

Em Inglês, *"Apply for a job"* significa *candidatar-se a uma vaga de emprego*. Tanto o [google](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/apply%20for%20a%20job) quanto o [linguee](http://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/apply+for+a+job.html) traduzem a expressão como **candidatar-se a um emprego**.

Porém, tenho visto que muitas pessoas - sobretudo das áreas de RH das empresas - estão usando o verbo **aplicar** ao invés de **candidatar**:

- [Este site](http://trabalhandonoexterior.com.br/empregos-no-canada-para-brasileiros/), por exemplo, usa *"aplicar para vagas de emprego"*
- [Este artigo do wikiHow](https://pt.wikihow.com/se-Aplicar-a-um-Emprego-Pessoalmente) tem o título *"Como se Aplicar a um Emprego Pessoalmente"*
- [Este outro site](https://goenning.net/2016/12/29/dicas-para-conseguir-um-emprego-no-exterior-estando-no-brasil/) também usa várias vezes a expressão *"aplicar para as vagas"*
- Encontrei até um [projeto no bitbucket](https://searchcode.com/file/133396213/JobRoller/1.0/pt_BR.po) que usa a mesma tradução:

  ```
  msgid "Apply for this Job"
  msgstr "Aplicar para esta Vaga"
  ```
- e muitos outros...

Além dos exemplos online, tenho percebido cada vez mais pessoas usando o verbo **aplicar** como sinônimo de **candidatar-se** (a uma vaga de emprego), não só na escrita, mas também na fala.

Apesar disso, os dicionários parecem discordar. O [priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aplicar) e a [infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/aplicar) até registram **empregar** como um dos signficados, mas com certeza não é relacionado a um emprego (trabalho). Tanto que o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/aplicar/) esclarece que **empregar**, no caso, significa **pôr em prática**. Mas em nenhum dos dicionários há o significado de **candidatar-se a uma vaga** nem nada parecido.

Minha dúvida é se este uso do verbo **aplicar** está correto (e talvez os dicionários ainda não tenham oficializado), ou se trata de mais um daqueles casos de traduções erradas, mas que acabam se popularizando.

Comment: É um uso bem fora de forma e sentido. Candidatar-se é o uso comum para quem se inscreve por formulários de agências de emprego ou apresenta currículos quando estão procurando emprego. Essa forma aplicar-se inclusive assume a ideia de procurar emprego e se candidatar a um emprego ficando ainda pior sua concepção com base em achismos de traduções equivocadas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse *aplicar* no sentido ‘candidatar-se’ é claramente um neologismo recente: tradicionalmente, *aplicar a* nunca significou ‘candidatar-se a’. Daí que *aplicar* não apareça com esse sentido nem nos dicionários online, como já verificaste, nem no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) ou Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001).

Sim, *aplicar* vem com o sentido ‘empregar’ na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/aplicar), [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aplicar), [Aulete 2 e 7](http://www.aulete.com.br/aplicar) e [Michaelis 2](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/aplicar/), mas isto nada tem que ver com *candidatar-se*; antes se emprega em frases como:

> Aplicou os conhecimentos adquiridos na resolução de novos problemas.
>
> Aplicou a sua fortuna em vários investimentos na região.

Que esse *aplicar* no sentido de *candidatar-se* é um neologismo inspirado no inglês *apply for* é aliás reconhecido por pessoas que o usam ou ouvem. Por exemplo, Chrys Chrystello, nesta [palestra num congresso da Sociedade de Língua Portuguesa (1999)](https://www.academia.edu/33365505/a_p%C3%A1tria_n%C3%A3o_%C3%A9_a_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa_para_os_luso-australianos_palestra_SLP-nov_1999?auto=download), identificou esse *aplicar* como neologismo entre luso-descendentes na Austrália (outros são *bossa* ‘patroa’ e *levar o saco* ‘ser de despedido’, de *get the sack*). Um estudante brasileiro na Suiça [(André Sarli, *Revoando*, 2017)](http://revoando.com/2017/03/19/quando-nem-tudo-da-certo-recusa-no-phd/), também diz que lá em vez de *candidatura* “a gente fala aplicação, um neologismo que vem do Inglês por ‘apply’”.

Pronto, isto são os factos. Agora, se este *aplicar* é correto já é uma questão mais complicada. A *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014) tem quatro páginas (p. 6-10) com uma discussão resumida de várias noções de correto. E a Pontíficia Universidade Católica do Rio Grande Sul tem um artigo muito mais longo sobre o assunto, [*Concepções de Língua e Reflexos na Prática do Professor* de Gilberto Scarton](http://pucrs.br/manualred/textos/texto7.php). Uma posição defendida é que o correto depende do contexto comunicacional—formal, coloquial, grupo, etc.

Nesta linha, eu não vou acusar ninguém de não saber falar português, mas eu pessoalmente nunca usaria este *aplicar* a não ser por brincadeira, com ênfase no *aplicar* e junto de pessoas que compreendessem a brincadeira. E recomendo o uso de *candidatar* em vez de *aplicar* em qualquer contexto que tenha um mínimo de formalidade.

Talvez este uso se dissemine e venha a impor-se e a ser reconhecido nos dicionários. Mas por enquanto estamos em 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimamente muita gente tem traduzido "apply" como "aplicar" nos casos de emprego, mas isso não é comum de se usar (todas as vezes que vi "aplicar" neste sentido eram pessoas que traduziram a palavra do inglês, mas nunca vi no dia a dia). É mais comum usar, quando neste sentido, a expressão "candidatar".

Apply for a job = Candidatar(-se) ao um emprego